# Learning about objects and how to encapsulate assigned variable to private variable

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

I'm trying to write a program in Java that displays the name, type, grams, steeping and double steeping time of a tea to practice learning class/objects/methods.

I'm getting errors, hoping someone could help shed some light.

```
public class Tea {

    private String Name;
    private String Type;
    private int GramsPerCup;
    private int SteepingMinutes;

    public Tea()//default constructor, takes no args, must be same name as class
    {
    }

    public Tea(String Name, String Type, int GramsPerCup, int SteepingMinutes)//constructor that takes arguments
    {
        Name = Name;
        Type = Type;
        GramsPerCup = GramsPerCup;
        SteepingMinutes = SteepingMinutes;
    }

    public void DoubleSteep() {
        int TeaDoubleSteep = SteepingMinutes * 2;
    }

    public String PrintDetails() {
        return "Name: " + Name + "\n" + "Type: " + Type + "/n" + "Grams Per Cup: " + GramsPerCup + "\n" + "Steeping Time in Minutes: " + SteepingMinutes + "\n" + "For dark brew, steep: " + DoubleSteep + " minutes";

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Tea tea1 = new Tea("Earl Grey", "Black", 3, 5);
        tea1.DoubleSteep();
        System.out.println(tea1.PrintDetails());
    }
}
```

Please be kind, I'm very new to this, Thank you!:)

Comment: the compiler is a very good friend you should get along with, as it will clearly specify what the issue is. Also, please follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Most of your errors are probably caused by typo errors. Your compiler will tell you which line and where exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just a Hint!**

You have more then one error in your code :

First :

To create a new Object you have to use `new` then `space` then the name of your class :

```
Tea tea1 = newTea("Earl Grey", "Black", 3, 5);//wrong

Tea tea1 = new Tea("Earl Grey", "Black", 3, 5);//correct
//---------^^^^------------------------------------------Note that
```

Second:

To call a method in another class you have to use `className.methodName()`, not :

```
System.out.println(tea1, PrintDetails());
//---------------------^^--------To call a method in another class you have to use dot(.)
```

Use this instead :

```
System.out.println(tea1.PrintDetails());
```

Third :

You assign in your constructor wrong value :

```
public Tea(String Name, String Type, int GramsPerCup, int SteepingMinutes)
{
    Name = TeaName;
    //----^^^^^^^^--------Thie name is not exist in your method signature
    //same to the others
}
```

You have to use:

```
this.Name = Name;
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot! I'm using programmr.com and getting only one more error:   
32
Description: class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java public class Main { ^. 
I've added a class called 'Main'. Is there something I need to write in that class, like "package tea;"? I can't seem to figure that one out. Thank you! @YCF_L